# Java multithreading: Passing camera frame to running worker thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ftp, streaming

I am using OpenCV4Android and capturing camera frames, so each time a frame has been captured, the method `Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)` is called. Inside that method I receive the frames in a `Mat` object (`mRgba`).

When a button has been clicked, I start sending out those frames to a connected FTP server. When that button has been clicked again, I stop sending the frames. I need to be putting this on a separate thread, as sending out these frames causes a lot of GUI lag.

What I am struggling to conceptualize and code is... to be able to have one thread that starts and stops on button clicked, and initialize and start the thread once - when started, receives each camera frame from the camera and pushes that camera frame out to the FTP server.

Currently I have this:

```
public class FdActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 { 

    private FTPImage ftp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //connect to FTP server
        ftp = new FTPImage();   

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String ftpResult = ftp.connectToFTP(config.getFtpIP());
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();       
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        if (isRecordFrames) {       
            Bitmap bmp;
            try {
                //convert Mat to Bitmap
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);         
                Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);  
                //scale down Bitmap
                final Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth()/2, bmp.getHeight()/2, false);

                //issue - this is going to create a Runnable for each frame     
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ftp.writeImageToFTP(scaledBmp);
                    }
                };
                new Thread(runnable).start();   
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception onCameraFrame");
            }
        }   
        return mRgba;
    }
}
```

FTPImage Class:

```
public class FTPImage {

    private FTPClient ftpClient = null;

    public String connectToFTP(String ftpIP) {
        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        String reply = "";

        try {
            ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ftpIP));

            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }       
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();          
            ftpClient.login("anonymous", "");       
            reply = ftpClient.getReplyString();         

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                { }
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reply;
    }

    public void writeImageToFTP(Bitmap b) {
        if (ftpClient != null) {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    boolean res = ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();         
                    b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()));

                    res = ftpClient.storeFile("testImg.jpg", buffIn);
                    //when res returns, storeFile has finished uploading
                    String reply = ftpClient.getReplyString();

                    buffIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void disconnectFromFTP() {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout(); 
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass each camera frame to a single, separate, running thread which then sends out that frame to a FTP server?

I hope that makes sense... just having trouble with the threading part. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to add Thread UploadThread here :

```
public class FdActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 { 

private FTPImage ftp;

// declaration
private UploadThread mUploadThread;
private Handler mUploadHandler;
public static int UPLOAD_IMAGE = 11;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// initialization
mUploadThread = new UploadThread(this);
mUploadThread.start();
    //connect to FTP server
    ftp = new FTPImage();   

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String ftpResult = ftp.connectToFTP(config.getFtpIP());
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();       
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (isRecordFrames) {       
        Bitmap bmp;
        try {
            //convert Mat to Bitmap
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);         
            Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);  
            //scale down Bitmap
            final Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth()/2, bmp.getHeight()/2, false);



    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.what = UPLOAD_IMAGE;
    mUploadHandler.sendMessage(msg);    // this way we send message to upload thread queue
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception onCameraFrame");
        }
    }   
    return mRgba;
}

Thread UploadThread = new Thread() {
    private Context;
    public UploadThread(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mUploadHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(msg) {
                case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
                ftp.writeImageToFTP(scaledBmp);     // uploading    
                break;              
            }
        }               


        Looper.loop();

        }
};
```

Comment: I feel if you use AsynkTask instead of Thread then it will be better for your case

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did not even think about using Looper, so I'm looking into it now.